# What does it mean by Decimal(-1)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently working on some web project based on Django & during this web development I have faced below kind of code which I am not able to understand properly.

```
if price_product['price'] == Decimal('-1'):
   is_price_exist = False
```

In above code price_product['price'] = '142.56' kind of values.I have test it with different kind of negative & positive values of price_product['price'] but everytime condition become false.

My question is what does it mean by Decimal('-1') & how it works?
When will be above condition become True?
Thanks.

Comment: It'll be equal when the price is `-1`… [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is just a precise version of floats. This means whatever the author wants it to mean; perhaps they assign `-1` to some prices to have a special meaning (which is not usually good practice, but there you are).

Comment: What is difference if I replace code with `if price_product['price'] == '-1'` ?

Comment: You would want to compare against the integer `-1`, not the string `'1'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if price_product['price'] == Decimal('-1'):`
Above code comparing value of `price_product['price']` with Decimal type -1 value.

if `price_product['price']` value will be of Decimal type -1 value then above conditions become true.

For further explanation you can refer python doc related to Decimal.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

My question is what does it mean by Decimal('-1') & how it works?

[how it works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

When will be above condition become True?

```
price_product['price'] = -1 then the condition become true
`from decimal import *
price_product={}
price_product['price']= -1
is_price_exist = True
if price_product['price'] == Decimal('-1'):
   is_price_exist = False
print is_price_exist`
```